# Is there a way to lock a table in node.js pg

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Running node.js pg and am having a deadlock issue with a CTE upsert statement. I'm getting a deadlock when trying to run the query statement. I want to know if there is a way to lock the table (in node.js pg) so that I won't run into this issue.

```
pg.connect(constring, function(err, client, done) {

            if(err) { console.error('Error (updateHapiActivities: human_api_activities__c)           connecting to DB ... : ' + err );
                    } else {
                            var queryConfig = "WITH upsert AS (UPDATE salesforce.human_api_activities__c SET calories__c = ($1), distance__c = ($2), steps__c = ($3), id__c = ($4), updatedat__c = ($5) WHERE userid__c = ($8) AND $
                            client.query(queryConfig, [new_cal, new_dis, new_step, wearable_id, update_time, date, create_time, user_id, source], function(err, result) {
                                    if(err) { console.error('Error (updateHapiActivities: human_api_activities__c) updating query ... : ' + err);
                                    } else {
                                            var devArr = result.rows;
                                            client.end();
                            }); // end upsert query
                    }       // end else
            }); // end connection
```

I tried putting a client.query("BEGIN;") ... and then after client.query("LOCK table IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE" ... but it was erroring out with LOCK TABLE can only be used in transaction blocks.

Any help?

Comment: So your issue isn't how to lock a table, but how to do multi-statement transactions, really.

Comment: yeah, that would be better

Comment: would be best for an upsert in postgres instead of this